# Get String from List of Maps in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have: `List<Map<String, String>> countries` and I was able to get value which I am interested in by this:

```
    String value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> map = countries.get(i);
        if (map.containsValue(country)) {
            value = map.get(COUNTRY_NAME);
        }
    }
    return value;
```

so in general - if in map is country which I am interested in then I take value where key is COUNTRY_NAME.

How can I translate it to streams? I tried this way:

```
for (Map<String, String> m : countries) {
        description = String.valueOf(m.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(map -> map.getValue().equals(country))
                .findFirst());
        }
```

but first it doesn't work, second I still used for each loop.

Comment: Needing the presence of a particular value, regardless of the associated key, is a very strange requirement. Also, `containsValue(country)` will search the entire map linearly and you’re repeating that for every map until a match has been found, which is quite expensive and defeats the purpose of maps to provide an efficient lookup for a specific *key*.

Comment: Good point, thank you @Holger! To be honest my map is small, max n=9 elements so I didn't care about linear search O(n) but nice spoting.

Comment: @Holger, `Needing the presence of a particular value, regardless of the associated key, is a very strange requirement` - it's not true.I take value of the associated key. if `(map.containsValue(country)) then value = map.get(COUNTRY_NAME);` also with streams (@Eklavya answer) there is filter first and then takes value so there will be only one after filtering.

Comment: There is no connection between `containsValue(country)` and `map.get(COUNTRY_NAME)`. The former tells whether the *value* `country` is present, regardless of the associated key, while the latter will return the associated value for the *key* `COUNTRY_NAME` which is not necessarily `country`. In fact, if the key `COUNTRY_NAME` is associated with the value `country`, the whole operation makes even less sense. Why would anyone perform a map lookup when they know the associated value beforehand? This has nothing to do with loops nor streams, it makes no sense in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter map if it's `containsValue` then transform your data using `.map()` then after `.findFirst()` use `.orElse()` to return default value if not found.

```
String value = countries.stream()
                        .filter(m -> m.containsValue(country))
                        .map(m -> m.get(COUNTRY_NAME))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse("");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try:

```
Stream.of(countries).reduce(Stream::concat)
                    .filter(map -> map.getValue().equals(country))
                    .findFirst();
```

[That page](https://www.techempower.com/blog/2016/10/19/efficient-multiple-stream-concatenation-in-java/) seems to show things that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
       Optional<Map<String, String>> countryOpt = countries
           .stream()
           .filter(c -> c.containsValue(COUNTRY_NAME))
           .findAny();
       if (countryOpt.isPresent()) {
           value = countryOpt.get().get(COUNTRY_NAME);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Optional<String> countryOptional = countries.stream()
            .filter(kvp -> kvp.containsKey(COUNTRY_NAME))
            .map(kvp -> kvp.get(COUNTRY_NAME))
            .findFirst();
```